# Magento, Adding external <script> and <style> in cms blocks?

Tags: magento-1.8, cms

I already done my static blocks and linked them to category pages, but now every block has its css and script inside the every page, I want to move them to one css file and one script file, so if I need to make any change it will be done in all pages at ones rather that doing it one by one.

I hope I was clear.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are the blocks only added on category pages?

Comment: yes it been added to category pages and subcategory pages, thank you David for reply